# My .framework doesn't seem to be generated

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks, ios-library

I'm currently trying to maintain a library that was written internally in order to update our cocoaPods repository. In order to do that I've got to be able to get the .framework that's supposed to be generated when i build the library (I guess, I'm more than new to the the entire Xcode/iOS world)

I found the build phase menu where I found a submenu called "Prepare Framework" I guess it's here that everything is going on ..

Here is what's there:

[image]

```
set -e

mkdir -p "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"

# Link the "Current" version to "A"
/bin/ln -sfh A "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/Current"
/bin/ln -sfh Versions/Current/Headers "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Headers"
/bin/ln -sfh "Versions/Current/${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/${PRODUCT_NAME}"

# The -a ensures that the headers maintain the source modification date so that we don't constantly
# cause propagating rebuilds of files that import these headers.
/bin/cp -a "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

The thing is when I build the library, I never find the .framework I do need ..

I think there might have an error on that side. If you guys could help me..

Guillaume :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the last line of your script

```
/bin/cp -a "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

There's either supposed to be a backslash there, or you should write the path in single line (inside the same set of double quotes)

```
/bin/cp -a "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/" \ 
 "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```

or

```
/bin/cp -a "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
```